# Configuration file of Ansible does not seems to accept my Jinja variable

Tags: ansible, yaml, jinja2

I tried to modify my default inventory list from `/etc/ansible/hosts` to `$HOME/.ansible/inventory_list`, below is my attempt (  I assume `ANSIBLE_HOME` point to my Ansible configuration path which is `$HOME/.ansible`).

```ini
inventory={{ ANSIBLE_HOME ~ "/inventory_list" }}
```

But this doesn't work, upon viewing with `ansible-config dump --only-changed`, I see this instead.

```bash
$ ansible-config dump --only-changed
DEFAULT_HOST_LIST(/home/liso/.ansible.cfg) = ['/home/liso/{{ ANSIBLE_HOME }}']
```

I expect this to be `DEFAULT_HOST_LIST(/home/liso/.ansible.cfg) = ['/home/liso/.ansible/inventory_list']`.

Can anyone help me figure out this problem?
I installed Ansible via `pip3 install ansible`.

Comment: The configuration file is **not** a Jinja templated file.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε but the example config uses variable https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#ansible-configuration-settings. If so how can I reliably point to my configuration path within the `ansible.cfg` file ?

Comment: It uses **shell** variables, not Jinja ones. You want `inventory=$HOME/.ansible/inventory_list`, as your actual description says it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration file of Ansible is not a Jinja templated file.
It does indeed accepts variables but only environment variables, and a really specific `{{CWD}}` macro as described in the section [*"Relative paths for configuration"*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#relative-paths-for-configuration).

In the same section, you can read:

> You can specify a relative path for many configuration options. In most of those cases the path used will be relative to the `ansible.cfg` file used for the current execution.

<sup>*Source: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#relative-paths-for-configuration*</sup>

So, that means that, in your case, since your configuration file is `/home/liso/.ansible.cfg`, you could just go by

```ini
inventory=.ansible/inventory_list
```

Or you can use the `$HOME` environment variable:

```ini
inventory=$HOME/.ansible/inventory_list
```